# How to calculate current value that depends on previous value without using LOOP?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, window-functions

I am trying to implement the below calculation in SQL. Currently, I am using PL/SQL (or PLPGSQL) with FOR LOOP and couple of variables to calculate this for every row - which, of course, is extremely inefficient. Is there a way to accomplish this using window functions or so?

For the first row, current value should be some fixed value. For following rows,

[image: formula]

EDIT:

Relevant Formulas:

```
Group-Return = IF(Period = 1, 0, SUMPRODUCT([Type-AA-Return]:[Type-BB-Return], [PREV Group-AA-Actual]:[PREV Group-BB-Actual] ))
Group-AA-Actual = IF(Period = 1, AA-Target, PREV Value/(1 + Group Return))
```

Similarly for the BB & CC

Sample data:

First four columns are static data. Everything else is formula.

| GROUP | Period | Type-AA-Return | Type-BB-Return | Group-Return | Group-Growth | AA-Target | BB-Target | CC-Target | Group-AA-Actual | Group-BB-Actual | Group-CC-Actual |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GROUP-ONE | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1000 | 0.8 | 0.19 | 0.01 | 0.8 | 0.19 | 0.01 |
| GROUP-ONE | 2 | -0.0040289 | -0.0040209 | -0.003987091 | 996.012909 | 0.8 | 0.19 | 0.01 | 0.799966419 | 0.189993551 | 0.010040031 |
| GROUP-ONE | 3 | -0.003768282 | -0.008660322 | -0.004659904 | 991.371584 | 0.8 | 0.19 | 0.01 | 0.800683026 | 0.189229939 | 0.010087035 |
| GROUP-ONE | 4 | -0.041907121 | 0.006951106 | -0.032238963 | 959.410792 | 0.8 | 0.19 | 0.01 | 0.792684016 | 0.19689292 | 0.010423064 |
| GROUP-ONE | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| GROUP-ONE | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| GROUP-ONE | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| GROUP-ONE | 12 | -0.079204478 | -0.000449001 | -0.063450162 | 950.886857 | 0.8 | 0.19 | 0.01 | 0.75 | 0.24 | 0.01 |
| GROUP-TWO | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1000 | 0.8 | 0.19 | 0.01 | 0.8 | 0.19 | 0.01 |
| GROUP-TWO | 2 | -0.0040289 | -0.0040209 | -0.003987091 | 996.012909 | 0.8 | 0.19 | 0.01 | 0.799966419 | 0.189993551 | 0.010040031 |
| GROUP-TWO | 3 | -0.003768282 | -0.008660322 | -0.004659904 | 991.371584 | 0.8 | 0.19 | 0.01 | 0.800683026 | 0.189229939 | 0.010087035 |
| GROUP-TWO | 4 | -0.041907121 | 0.006951106 | -0.032238963 | 959.410792 | 0.8 | 0.19 | 0.01 | 0.792684016 | 0.19689292 | 0.010423064 |
| GROUP-TWO | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| GROUP-TWO | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| GROUP-TWO | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| GROUP-TWO | 12 | -0.079204478 | -0.000449001 | -0.063450162 | 950.886857 | 0.8 | 0.19 | 0.01 | 0.75 | 0.24 | 0.01 |

Comment: You are going to need to expand on this with an actual data sample and expected result. "value in another column calculated using previous value" is not clear to me.

Comment: I have added that info. Looks a lot more clunkier. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: In addition to sample data you need to post **expected results** of that data. Also explain your `Relevant Formulas` as from my point of view they are complete gibberish.

Comment: This contains the expected output - which are columns Group-Return and Group-AA-Actual. First four columns are static data. Everything else is formula.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the lag() function to get the value from previous row? So `lag(GROUP-AA-ACTUAL)` for example?
You probably also need to use `partition by` to get this working per group.
Check here if this helps: [oracle-lag-function-with-group-by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45698598/oracle-lag-function-with-group-by)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over a set of rows using `recursive common table expression (CTE)`, this way:

Input example data:

```
CREATE TABLE t (value integer);

INSERT INTO t VALUES (10), (5), (15), (1), (4);
```

Query:

First I generate rows number, so I can iterate one row at a time. Then I start from row number one, and get the next row (row number two). In the subquery after `UNION ALL` I get one row at a time (for each row I can access prevrious values (sq) and actual values (t_rn).

In my example `calc_value(n) = calc_value(n-1) / (1 + value(n))`.

```
WITH RECURSIVE t_rn AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rn, * FROM t),

               sq AS  (SELECT *, 10000.0 AS calc_value
                       FROM t_rn
                       WHERE rn = 1
                       
                       UNION ALL
                       
                       SELECT t_rn.rn, t_rn.value, (sq.calc_value / (1 + t_rn.value)) AS calc_value 
                       FROM sq
                       INNER JOIN t_rn ON sq.rn + 1 = t_rn.rn)

SELECT value, ROUND(calc_value, 2)
FROM sq
ORDER BY rn;
```

Output:

| value | calc_value |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | 10000.00 |
| 5 | 1666.67 |
| 15 | 104.17 |
| 1 | 52.08 |
| 4 | 10.42 |

[Fiddle!](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=26e3618e38c638a87c235ef7845b2cfb)